# Run Timer in Backgrounf in flutter

Tags: flutter, timer, background

I want Run Timer In Background also even if user closed app. And don't stop until user do not stops even app closed.
I tried stream but it stop when app closed.
So Please Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run clock timer in background on flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480124/how-to-run-clock-timer-in-background-on-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thank you for giving answer**

But I find solution like current time save in local device using SharedPreferences and when user open app again then find difference between
saved time and currenttime show in my app

here is my code

```
    startTimer() {
    timerStream = stopWatchStream();
    timerSubscription = timerStream.listen((int newTick) {
      String time = _sharedPreferences.getString("time");
      Duration duration = DateTime.now().difference(DateTime.parse(time));

      setState(() {
        hoursStr = ((duration.inSeconds / (60 * 60)) % 60)
            .floor()
            .toString()
            .padLeft(2, '0');
        minutesStr =
            ((duration.inSeconds / 60) % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
        secondsStr =
            (duration.inSeconds % 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package - https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

I'm also attaching this video, this can solve your problems - https://youtu.be/A4_L959tRuM