# How to run timer even app in background or foreground in flutter?

Tags: flutter, timer

i want to hide button for specific time when user tapped on button, and the button show when time is completed, even app in foreground or background

Comment: You can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480124/how-to-run-clock-timer-in-background-on-flutter

Comment: i tried but not full fill my scenario, basically i have multiple medicine and one button thats name is  "take medicine" when user tapped on this button this button hide according to time but in others medicine this button show until take medicine

Answer (score 0):

the ultimate solution is to use foreground services, and with android, it comes with a sticky notification to prevent the system from killing the app.