# I want to implement Timer in flutter that is capable of running in background

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I want to implement Timer in flutter that is capable of running in background despite when the phone is locked. I have tried Timer.periodic and isolates but both of them **do not** run in background or when the phone is locked. And also I also came across the logic of saving the timestamp when going to background and comparing that same time while coming to foreground, but that is not feasible in my case. So Anything else do you know apart from these would be helpful.

Comment: You generally don't get background execution as you wish on mobile, because it kills batteries.  This question has been asked and answered many times before, with the same answers repeatedly.

Comment: only provide solutions if you really have otherwise dont waste time here in giving vague statements. @RandalSchwartz

Comment: this was a comment, not a solution.  It was a comment about the quality and redundancy of the question.

Comment: this was a comment, not a solution.  It was a comment about the quality and redundancy of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in cache when you start your timer and when you stop your timer, you differentiate between now and the value you stored in cache.

Comment: this is not feasible for my usecase and I have already mentioned this in the description.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand that.
I found an article that talks about the same problem as you, and the answer is interesting
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59480263/18290590
And article explain what to do countdown Timer works in Background
https://navinkumar0118.medium.com/flutter-countdown-timer-works-in-background-f87488b0ba4c#:~:text=To%20run%20the%20timer%20on,on%20both%20native%20side%20classes.